# Increase numbers of elements in array of strings in C

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays, realloc

I'm beginner in the studies of C language (not C++) and I'm trying to define a dynamic array of strings, but I'm experiencing difficulties for appending an element.

I have tried to define the array as:

```
char **e = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
e[0] = "abc";
e[1] = "def";
e[2] = "ghi";
```

It ran successfully, but trying to resize it, using:

```
  **e = realloc(e, 4 * sizeof(char *));
```

Returned the error: "*assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast*". What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Fábio

Comment: Get rid of the `**` in your assignment: `e = realloc(e, 4 * sizeof(char *));`

Comment: And check the return values of `malloc()` and `realloc()` before using them.  Both functions can fail and, if they do, subsequent behaviour of code using the returned values will be undefined.

Comment: Fabio, did you get the info you needed? Are you going to accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

```
e = realloc(e, 4 * sizeof(char *));
```

Long answer:

Let's split your original declaration `char **e = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));` into declaration and assignment.

```
char **e;
e = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
```

The first line introduces the variable `e` and specifies its type `char **`. The second line assigns the expression that you put on the right side of the `=` sign to the newly declared variable.

To assign a new value to `e`, you modify the second line to read:

```
e = realloc(e, 4 * sizeof(char *));
```

Comment: If `realloc` fails and returns `NULL` you lose the original array. Store the result of `realloc` in a temporary variable first.

Answer (score 0):

This is the refined code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
        char **e = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
        e[0] = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
        e[1] = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
        e[2] = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(e[0], "abc");
        strcpy(e[1], "def");
        strcpy(e[2], "ghi");
        puts(e[0]);
        puts(e[1]);
        puts(e[2]);
}
```

Some problems found in your code:

1. To allocate memory to a pointer, write `ptr = malloc(1)`, not `malloc(ptr, 1)`.
2. `e` is a "pointer to pointer to char", while `e[0]` to `e[2]` are "pointers to char". So when mallocing e, use `sizeof (char *)`, and when mallocing `e[x]', use`sizeof (char)` instead.
3. `*e = "abc";` only copy the address of the string literal, not the value it contains. To copy the whole char array, you have to write `strcpy(e[0], "abc");`.

Comment: Sun Qingyao, do we need, then, to allocate memory for every single element of the array?

Comment: @FábioSoldá No. For example, `e[0] = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));` has allocated memory for all of its elements: e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3]